# Relatively compact sequence in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{f_n\}_n$ be a sequence in $L^2(\mathbb R)$. Suppose that there exists a sequence of closed balls $B_k \subset \mathbb R$ such that, for all $n$,
$$ \int_{\mathbb R - B_k} |f_n|^2 \leq \frac{1}{k} $$
Let $\{\psi_k\}$ be a sequence of bump functions in $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ taking the value one on $B_k$, and suppose I know that $\{\psi_k f_n\}_n$ is relatively compact in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, for each $k$.

Can I find some $g \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ and a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}_k$ of $\{f_n\}_n$ such that $\psi_k f_{n_k} \to g$?

Is $\{f_n\}_n$ relatively compact?

Answer (score 2):

Write $f_k=\psi_kf_k +(1-\psi_k) f_k$ and assume that $\psi_k f_k \to g$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (perhaps after passing to a subsequence, this is possible by assumption). Then we calculate
$$
\| f_k -g\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} \leq \| \psi_kf_k -g\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} + \| (1-\psi_k)f_k\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} \leq \| \psi_k f_k -g\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} +C\| f_k\|_{(L^2(\mathbb{R}\setminus B_k)}
$$
$$
\leq \| \psi_k f_k -g\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} +Ck^{-1/2}.
$$